# Android SDK does not add publish permissions from Facebook

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-emulator

I'm working in a android app where a person may do a facebook login.

I'm trying to do the "share" option to post something about my app in the person's timeline, but i'm having the following issue:

```
Session: an attempt was made to request new permissions for a session that has a pending request
```

Here is the mainActivity and the fragment. This code derives almost completely  by facebook sdk examples

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private MainFragment mainFragment;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
            mainFragment = new MainFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment)
            .commit();
        } else {
            // Or set the fragment from restored state info
            mainFragment = (MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
        }
    }
}
```

**Fragment:**

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment{

    private static final String TAG = "MainFragment";
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

    private Button shareButton;

    private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
    private static final String PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY = "pendingPublishReauthorization";
    private boolean pendingPublishReauthorization = false;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
            ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
        shareButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.shareButton);
        LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
        authButton.setFragment(this);
        authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_likes", "user_status"));
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            pendingPublishReauthorization = 
                savedInstanceState.getBoolean(PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY, false);
        }

        shareButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.shareButton);
        shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                publishStory();        
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(getActivity(), requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            shareButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (pendingPublishReauthorization && 
                    state.equals(SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED)) {
                pendingPublishReauthorization = false;
                publishStory();
            }
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            shareButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // For scenarios where the main activity is launched and user
        // session is not null, the session state change notification
        // may not be triggered. Trigger it if it's open/closed.
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null &&
               (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
        }

        uiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean(PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY, pendingPublishReauthorization);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    private void publishStory() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

        if (session != null){

            // Check for publish permissions    
            List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
            if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
                pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
                Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                        .NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
            session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
                return;
            }

            Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
            postParams.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");
            postParams.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
            postParams.putString("description", "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");

            Request.Callback callback= new Request.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    JSONObject graphResponse = response
                                               .getGraphObject()
                                               .getInnerJSONObject();
                    String postId = null;
                    try {
                        postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.i(TAG,
                            "JSON error "+ e.getMessage());
                    }
                    FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                    if (error != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity()
                             .getApplicationContext(),
                             error.getErrorMessage(),
                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity()
                                 .getApplicationContext(), 
                                 postId,
                                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            };

            Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams, 
                                  HttpMethod.POST, callback);

            RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
            task.execute();
        }

    }

    private boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> subset, Collection<String> superset) {
        for (String string : subset) {
            if (!superset.contains(string)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

** MainActivity's XML**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/authButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/shareButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Share"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

LogCat:

```
07-08 16:07:49.916: E/AndroidRuntime(710): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-08 16:07:49.916: E/AndroidRuntime(710): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Session: an attempt was made to request new permissions for a session that has a pending request.
07-08 16:07:49.916: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at com.facebook.Session.requestNewPermissions(Session.java:1245)
07-08 16:07:49.916: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at com.facebook.Session.requestNewPublishPermissions(Session.java:592)
07-08 16:07:49.916: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at com.example.facebooksharedemo.MainFragment.publishStory(MainFragment.java:146)
07-08 16:07:49.916: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at com.example.facebooksharedemo.MainFragment.onSessionStateChange(MainFragment.java:79)
07-08 16:07:49.916: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at com.example.facebooksharedemo.MainFragment.access$0(MainFragment.java:73)
07-08 16:07:49.916: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at com.example.facebooksharedemo.MainFragment$1.call(MainFragment.java:89)
07-08 16:07:49.916: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at com.facebook.Session$4$1.run(Session.java:1542)
07-08 16:07:49.916: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
07-08 16:07:49.916: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-08 16:07:49.916: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-08 16:07:49.916: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-08 16:07:49.916: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-08 16:07:49.916: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-08 16:07:49.916: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-08 16:07:49.916: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-08 16:07:49.916: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The Login process is flowing correctly, but when i try to add the publish permission clicking in the "share" button, it does not add the permission and try the run the Request twice.

Is this a problem with the android emulator? Could someone help me?

Comment: those permissions need to get approved by the facebook team before they can be used by non-app-admins. maybe that is the problem?

Comment: The weird thing is that the app doesn't ask for publish permissions. It just say "you already authorized the app". It only ask for permissions in the first time you log, and only the login permissions (public_profile, email...)

Comment: of course the app does not ask for permissions not approved yet. you can still authorize it without those permissions. again, those specific permissions need to get approved. see here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog